# UVa 162 - Beggar My Neighbour

Tags: java, algorithm

The logic is very simple, but I don't know why my code is getting WA. If you can point out something wrong with the logic, please help.

Problem: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&Itemid=99999999&page=show_problem&category=&problem=98&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+20986582

Source:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class UVa_00162 {

static Map<Character, Integer> faceCards = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
static {
    faceCards.put('A', 4);
    faceCards.put('K', 3);
    faceCards.put('Q', 2);
    faceCards.put('J', 1);
}
static Stack<String> dealerHand = new Stack<>();
static Stack<String> nonDealerHand = new Stack<>();
static Stack<String> table = new Stack<>();

static enum GameStatus {
    CONTINUE, DEALER_WIN, NONDEALER_WIN
};

static GameStatus status = GameStatus.CONTINUE;

static void play() {
    String curCard;
    boolean nonDealerTurn = true;
    int penalty;
    char key;

    while (true) {
        if (nonDealerHand.size() == 0) {
            status = GameStatus.DEALER_WIN;
            break;
        }
        if (dealerHand.size() == 0) {
            status = GameStatus.NONDEALER_WIN;
            break;
        }
        curCard = nonDealerTurn ? nonDealerHand.pop() : dealerHand.pop();
        table.push(curCard);
        nonDealerTurn = !nonDealerTurn;
        key = curCard.charAt(1);
        if (faceCards.containsKey(key)) {
            penalty = faceCards.get(key);
            while (penalty > 0) {
                if (nonDealerHand.size() == 0 || dealerHand.size() == 0) break;
                curCard = nonDealerTurn ? nonDealerHand.pop() : dealerHand.pop();
                --penalty;
                table.push(curCard);
                key = curCard.charAt(1);
                if (faceCards.containsKey(key)) {
                    penalty = faceCards.get(key);
                    nonDealerTurn = !nonDealerTurn;
                }
            }

            if (nonDealerHand.size() == 0) {
                status = GameStatus.DEALER_WIN;
                break;
            }
            if (dealerHand.size() == 0) {
                status = GameStatus.NONDEALER_WIN;
                break;
            }

            // place the heap face down under current hand 
            if (nonDealerTurn) {
                while (!table.isEmpty())
                    dealerHand.insertElementAt(table.remove(0), 0);
                nonDealerTurn = false;
            } else {
                while (!table.isEmpty())
                    nonDealerHand.insertElementAt(table.remove(0), 0);
                nonDealerTurn = true;
            }


        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;
    while(true) {
        s = input.next();
        if (s.equals("#")) break;
        nonDealerHand.push(s);
        dealerHand.push(input.next());
        int count = 3;
        while (count <= 52) {
            nonDealerHand.push(input.next());
            ++count;
            dealerHand.push(input.next());
            ++count;
        }

        play();

        if (status==GameStatus.DEALER_WIN)
            System.out.println("1 " + dealerHand.size());
        else
            System.out.println("2 " + nonDealerHand.size());

        nonDealerHand.clear();
        dealerHand.clear();
        table.clear();
        status = GameStatus.CONTINUE;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What does "getting WA" mean?

Comment: It means "Wrong Answer". Basically I was very upset because it just a matter of simulating the game (with just few simple rules). I'm quite lost low.